# visual studio windows mobile debugging not working

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, compact-framework

I can't hit any breakpoints while debugging a .NET CF mobile application from Visual Studio 2005 on Windows 6 professional emulator. Debugging starts, application is loaded on the device but all breakpoints are disabled. Any hints?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Just making sure: you are running in Debug mode right?

If you're debugging an older version than was previously on your device, you might want to remove it before deploying (it won't overwrite older versions).

Also this link came in handy after I messed up my project:

http://geekswithblogs.net/dbutscher/archive/2007/06/26/113472.aspx